# GateOne terminal emulator install on CentOs 7 (rpm build error)

Tags: python, linux, centos, rpm, gateone

I'd like to install GateOne emulator to practice for the Linux Foundation SysAdmin exam.  It has a setup.py file which tries to build an rpm from which to install it.  I have ensured rpm-build is installed. Would anyone know why I am getting the error at the end of this log, specifically in command rpm build, and a bad exit status.

```
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing requirements to gateone.egg-info/requires.txt
writing gateone.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to gateone.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to gateone.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to gateone.egg-info/entry_points.txt
file gateone.py (for module gateone) not found
reading manifest file 'gateone.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitignore'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.kate-swp' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pye' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.git' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.directory' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'gateone.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying gateone.egg-info to /home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gateone-1.2.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
Installing gateone script to /home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/usr/bin
file gateone.py (for module gateone) not found
writing list of installed files to 'INSTALLED_FILES'
Entry points were created for the following:
    console_scripts
        gateone = gateone.core.server:main
    go_applications
        example = gateone.applications.example
        terminal = gateone.applications.terminal
    go_plugins
        editor = gateone.plugins.editor
        help = gateone.plugins.help
    go_terminal_plugins
        bookmarks = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.bookmarks
        convenience = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.convenience
        example = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.example
        html = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.html
        logging = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.logging
        notice = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.notice
        playback = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.playback
        ssh = gateone.applications.terminal.plugins.ssh
+ sed -i -e 's/^.*$/"&"/g' INSTALLED_FILES
+ /usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh --strict-build-id -m --run-dwz --dwz-low-mem-die-limit 10000000 --dwz-max-die-limit 110000000 /home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD/gateone-1.2.0
/usr/lib/rpm/sepdebugcrcfix: Updated 0 CRC32s, 0 CRC32s did match.
find: 'debug': No such file or directory
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
/home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/usr/lib/systemd/system/gateone.service:ExecStart=/home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/usr/bin/gateone
/home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/etc/init.d/gateone:GATEONE=/home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64/usr/bin/gateone
Found '/home/wayne/Yandex.Disk/Courses/LinuxFoundation/GateOne-master/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/gateone-1.2.0-1.x86_64' in installed files; aborting
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KBhqQs (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KBhqQs (%install)
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I've never heard of the GateOne emulator, but if it is like many other rpms that have to be built and installed, it likely needs to be executed as root.

Comment: @DavidJenkins You [don't build RPMs as root](https://serverfault.com/questions/10027/why-is-it-bad-to-build-rpms-as-root). Only install them as root.

Comment: It says the problem at the end. The build system scans all the files being packaged and makes sure the temporary build location wasn't accidentally stored in a file. As you can see, the startup files accidentally stored your username, etc. That's bad. You'll need to patch them somehow in the spec file.

Comment: Interesting, but I may need to read up on how to do that, unless you elaborate.